# Why getting NullPointerException while using EntityManger directly in Spring boot Project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, entitymanager

I have create OnetoMany relation between two Entities `ProductCategory` and `DifferentProducts` and trying to persist `ProductCategory` by directly using `EntityManager`.
But When i am persisting the object using Below code i am getting `null-pointer Exception`.I have used `@PersistenceContext` annotation to make `EntityManager` instance to be managed by spring context.

```
public String AddProducts(){

        ProductCategory productCategory = new ProductCategory();
        ProductServiceImpl productService =new ProductServiceImpl();
        productCategory.setName("Type1");
        productService.saveProductCategory(productCategory);
        return "ProductAdded.. :)";
    }
```

**My Entity Classes:-**

```
@Entity
public class ProductCategory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {PERSIST,MERGE},fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<DifferentProducts> differentProducts;
    //getter and setters
}
```

**And Second:-**

```
@Entity
public class DifferentProducts {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String productname;
    private String cost;
    //getter and setter
}
```

**ProductServiceImpl Class:=**

```
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService{

    @Autowired
    private ProductsRepository productsRepository;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<ProductCategory> getAllProducts() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveProductCategory(ProductCategory productCategory) {
        entityManager.persist(productCategory);
    }
}
```

**Note:-**

*I have created tables in database in advance,according to JPA expectations.So, i have not included*
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update` *in my application.properties file.*

Thanks your Words are always value for me..!

Comment: Could you include the stacktrace as well?

Comment: `ProductServiceImpl productService =new ProductServiceImpl();` - you're instantiating the object yourself here so it won't be managed by Spring and any dependencies will not be injected

Comment: @darrengorman Thanks it worked.Thanks a lot.